# In passive voice does object become subject in real

Tags: sentence-structure, passive-voice

How can the object become subject in passive voice?

> Active: I am writing a letter.
> Passive: A letter is being written by me.

In this example **a letter** becomes the subject but *letter* is not doer of the verb so how can we say it is the subject?

So I want to know that in passive voice object become real subject or just comes on the position of subject.

Comment: "Subject" in this context is a ***syntactic*** attribute, so unquestionably ***a letter*** is the subject of the verb ***is***. The "thematic role" distinction you're thinking of is [***agent***](http://www.sfu.ca/~hedberg/Thematic_Roles.pdf) (the "actor", as opposed to the ***patient***, who *undergoes* the effects of an action).

Comment: "but *letter* is not doer of the verb" - in a way, it is.  The main verb of the sentence is now *to be* ("is"), not *to write* ("written").

Comment: Then who is the subject for verb write and what is the object for verb write in passive

Comment: @Hadman The subject of "written" is _understood_ as "I". There is no object in the passive of your particular example.

Comment: @Hadman In the sentence "A letter is being written by me", the subject of the sentence is "a letter".  There is no subject for the verb "write", because "written" is a past participle.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up grammar and semantics.

There is the *grammatical* subject.  This is the "noun phrase that goes before the verb".  The grammatical subject in the passive sentence "The letter is being written by me" is the noun phrase "the letter".

There is the grammatical object.  The is the noun phrase that follows the verb.  In the active sentence "I am writing the letter", the noun phrase "the letter" is an object, and the subject is "I".

Then there is the *semantic* role.  For example the "agent", "beneficiary" or "patient".  An "agent" is the thing (or person) that carries out an action. A "patient" is (in semantics) the thing (or person) that is affected by an event or that undergoes an event. There are lots more semantic roles.

In an active sentence, the semantic role of "agent" is indicated by the grammatical "subject", and the semantic role of "patient" is usually the grammatical object.

In a passive sentence the "patient" is the grammatical subject, and the "agent" is indicated by the optional "by ..." prepositional phrase.